# Using layers in Rgraphviz

Tags: r, graphviz

In Rgraphviz, how can I assign nodes and edges to particular layers, and plot only a selected layer or layers?

After perusing and searching the Rgraphviz documentation, I think I've figured out how to assign nodes and edges to particular layers -- but I still can't figure out how to plot only a selected layer.

[This "How to use layers" item on the graphviz wiki](http://www.graphviz.org/wiki/how-use-drawing-layers-overlays) implies that there should be a "layerselect" graph attribute that can be used to plot only a specified layer. However, [the list of allowed graph attributes in Rgraphviz](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Rgraphviz/html/GraphvizAttributes.html) does not include "layerselect." The "layers" graph attribute says "Only those components belonging to the current layer appear," but I can find no information on how to set (or even query) the "current layer."

I tried to do it anyway, but wasn't successful. Here's a reproducible example of my attempt:

```
require('Rgraphviz')

params <- LETTERS[1:5] #nodes A, B, C, D, E
edgelist <- vector('list', #set up edges
                   length=length(params))
names(edgelist) <- params
edgelist[['B']] <- c('E','A') #add edges from B to E and from B to A
edgelist[['A']] <- 'C' #add edge from A to C
edgelist[['D']] <- 'E' #add edge from D to E
graph.nel <- new('graphNEL', #construct graphNEL object
                 nodes=params,
                 edgeL=edgelist,
                 edgemode='directed')

#I want there to be two layers: 
#"redlayer", containing nodes A, B, C, E and the edges between them;
#"blacklayer", containing node D and the edge from D to E.

#Assign the colors and layers of the edges
eAttr <- list(color=c('B~A'='red', 
                      'A~C'='red', 
                      'B~E'='red',
                      'D~E'='black'), 
              layer=c('B~A'='redlayer', 
                      'A~C'='redlayer', 
                      'B~E'='redlayer',
                      'D~E'='blacklayer')
)
#Assign the colors and layers of the nodes
nAttr <- list(color=c(B='red', 
                      A='red', 
                      C='red', 
                      E='red',
                      D='black'), 
              layer=c(B='redlayer',
                      A='redlayer',
                      C='redlayer',
                      E='redlayer',
                      D='blacklayer'))

#Now plot
plot(graph.nel, 
     attrs=list(graph=list(layers='redlayer:blacklayer', #Define the two layers
                           layersep=':', #Explicitly define the layer separation character
                           layerselect='redlayer')), #Attempt to select only the 'redlayer' for plotting
     edgeAttrs=eAttr, #specify edge attributes
     nodeAttrs=nAttr #specify node attributes
     )
```

The result of the above code is the following plot:
[image: Rgraphviz plot]

However, I expected that only the nodes and edges colored red (i.e. those assigned to the layer named 'redlayer') would appear!

I've also tried

```
plot(graph.nel, 
         attrs=list(graph=list(layers='redlayer'), #Attempt to select only the 'redlayer' for plotting
         edgeAttrs=eAttr, #specify edge attributes
         nodeAttrs=nAttr #specify node attributes
         )
```

but it results in exactly the same plot -- that is, both layers are still being plotted.

Is there any way to plot only the layer named 'redlayer' in this example?